# Relative image paths for Twitter cards in blogdown

Tags: r, twitter, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to set up a template for generating Twitter Cards in `blogdown`. It put the following in `layouts/partials/twitter-card.html`:

```
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@myname">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@myname">
{{ if .IsPage }}
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ .Summary }}" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{{ .Title }}" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{ .Params.image }}" /> {{ else }}
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{{ .Site.Title }}" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ .Description }}" /> {{ end }}
```

And the following in `layouts/partials/head.html`:

```
{{ partial "twitter-card" . }}
```

In a given blogpost -- foo.Rmd -- I then put this in the YAML:

```
image: "static/post/foo/figure-html/some_image.png"
```

When I let hugo generate a post everything works fine and I get:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="static/post/fixed-points_files/figure-html/some_image.png" />
```

However, when I [preview my Twitter card](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)  the picture doesn't show up. I presume I would have to set a different path in the YAML front matter, but I can't find any documentation on what the path format should be, and all tutorials use absolute urls in their examples.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Twitter cards do not support relative paths, and you have to use a fully-qualified HTTP(S) URL in the image tag. This is described in the [troubleshooting](https://twittercommunity.com/t/not-whitelisted-unable-to-render-or-no-image-what-to-do-next/62736) post.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an absolute URL in this case:

```
image: "/post/foo/figure-html/some_image.png"
```

Note you should remove the directory name `static` ([Why?](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html)).

Comment: with Hugo Academic `serve_site()` converts a `baseurl` like `"https://strimas.com/"` to just `"/"`, which breaks the Twitter card. Given this, how do you suggest we get absolute paths to images in our Twitter cards using `blogdown`?

Comment: worth noting that `build_site()` uses the correct `baseurl` and the Twitter cards work, until you use `serve_site()`, which breaks them again

Comment: made a question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807293/blogdown-serve-site-removes-absolute-image-paths-for-twitter-cards